# element.innerHTML is not giving expected result in Javascipt

Tags: javascript, events, innerhtml

I'm not sure if my title for this question makes sense (Please suggest if it doesn't);

so i have this very simple examlpe.. in the HTML:

```
 <button class="btn" type="button"> button1 </button>
 <button class="btn" type="button"> button2 </button>
```

And in JS:

```
window.onload = () => {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

  buttons.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (btn.innerHTML === 'button1') {
        btn.style.background = 'green';
        console.log('Button1 is clicked');
      } else {
        btn.style.background = 'red';
        console.log('Button2 is clicked');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I thought it will behave like expected; but
any button i click its background turns red.

Can you please explain why is this happening?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to use `btn.innerHTML === '1'`? Won't the inner html be `'button1'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition `btn.innerHTML === '1'` is always *false* as the content of first button's *innerHTML* is *button1* and second button's *innerHTML* is *button1*.

You could try

```
if (btn.innerHTML.endsWith('1')){...
```

**Update:** There are some spaces around the text content. You should trim the value to remove the spaces. Also, I will suggest you to use *innerText* or *textContent* instead of *innerHTML* if the content is only string (no HTML):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

  buttons.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (btn.textContent.trim() === 'button1') {
        btn.style.background = 'green';
        console.log('Button1 is clicked');
      } else {
        btn.style.background = 'red';
        console.log('Button2 is clicked');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" type="button"> button1 </button>
<button class="btn" type="button"> button2 </button>
```

Comment: @shireefkhatab, updated the answer, please check:)

Answer (score 0):

You also used too many apostrophes in `type=""button"`
The correct way is `type="button"`.

Also, you could set IDs for both buttons like `id="1"`, and then check if btn.id === "1" or "2". That's a lot better than checking the html, in case you want to put actual text in there.